# How to properly return the count of resolved tickets based on category in Cell C

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's assume that Column C has 3 "categories": Shared, Team One, Team Two

The count for the resolved of each row is working, it returns the proper count for dates specified in fixed cells D$2 and D$3. "D" is unfixed at changes, to E, F, G, so on... Indicated calendar dates/weeks.

My dilemma is how to return the proper count for specified category, for example "Shared"
Assuming that the count returns 11, and 2 of that is "Shared"

How may I get the value to return just 2 based on my formula below?

```
=IF(C:C="Shared",COUNTIFS(resolved!$H:$H,">="&$D$2,resolved!$I:$I,"<="&$D$3),Error)
```

Any insight would help alot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you attach screenshots of sample data to make it easier to understand your problem?
What I don't understand yet is how the 'category' values in C:C are associated with the 'date' values in the 'resolved' sheet.

Comment: Hi @DattelKlauber and player0 
Please find image in this link
https://imgur.com/a/gPyFH40
Essentially Sheet2 should be able to pull the count only if it falls under Category A or Category B or C

Comment: @John Rehnald, your problem can be solved with the `COUNTIFS()` function alone where 2 criteria have to check for the 'resolved' date to be (1) smaller than the upper limit and (2) greater/equal to the lower limit and the 3rd criteria has to check for the (3) category to be equal. I'll write an answer assuming some of your requirements since it is still not perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data to look as shown in the screenshot below (sheet 1):

[image: data table]

and you want to count the number of 'resolved' items that fall into certain weekly intervals and certain categories {A,B,C} as shown in this screenshot (sheet 2):

[image: result table]

a possible solution would be the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(resolved!$I:$I,"<"&F$3,resolved!$I:$I,">="&F$2,resolved!$G:$G,"="&$E4)
```

which is written into the cell F4 from the example screenshot above. Also illustrated again here below:

[image: solution example]

Given that your date intervals in your 2nd sheet start with the same date that the previous interval ended with, make sure that the 2 criteria for the dates are not both smaller/greater and equal but only one of them also equal to the date criterium, otherwise you will count it twice in two sperate weekly intervals.

In other words, either you change your interval start and end dates such that there is no overlap, or you use the criteria combinations (`>` and `<=`) or (`>=` and `<`) but not (`<=` and `>=`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just did what you said and it's working! Let me check if the count is correct. My head can't seem to wrap around the formula yet. I'm slow these days. Need more brain food! LOL. Now I need to wrap my head around another issue. Let me create a new question for that one. Thank you for your help on this!